# drcsim: how do we reset BDI sim_interface error after fall and resume stand?

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If the robot falls, the behavior_feedback sets an error code and prevents the robot from entering anything other than USER mode.

Do we need to do anything other than return the robot to standing posture to resume BDI's MANIPULATION/STAND controls?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2934/drcsim:--how-do-we-reset-bdi-sim_interface-error-after-fall-and-resume-stand?/) by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 298 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [astaranowicz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/149/astaranowicz/) on 2013-05-22**:
I'm having this problem also.  It seems that the code has a bug so that when the acceleration is to high it actually freezes all the joints.

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-05-22**:
The BDI interface locks the joints (FREEZE) if robot falls to prevent controller from going unstable.  See user guide.  Once the robot falls, the system continues to report falling status, and it's not clear how this is cleared, or how to "reset" the BDI interface to enter STAND mode again if you get off the ground

**Comment by [astaranowicz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/149/astaranowicz/) on 2013-05-23**:
That makes sense, however, I would still consider this a bug because it doesn't clear the falling status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As mentioned in the [DRCSim User Guide](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/UserGuide#AtlasSimInterface_Behaviors), **Stand** mode is the hub to all the behavioral modes, I've added a diagram to clarify this point.  So to recover from a fall, you must first go back to **User** mode, then to **Stand** mode.  Below is an example path to recovery:

1. Put the robot under PID control, (i.e. set [`k_effort[0:28]`](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/367704bdd08af4f8471da3d647f0119afeef6f32/ros/atlas_msgs/msg/AtlasSimInterfaceCommand.msg?at=default#cl-38) to 255 for all joints), then
2. Get the robot back on to its feet with your own controller.  Drive Atlas into PID controlled `Stand` pose (for example, see [`VRCPlugin::SetPIDStand()`](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/367704bdd08af4f8471da3d647f0119afeef6f32/ros/atlas_msgs/VRCPlugin.cpp?at=default#cl-1250) for approximate target joint positions taken from a snapshot of joint states while standing).
3. Once the robot stabilizes, you can then switch to [BDI `STAND` mode](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/367704bdd08af4f8471da3d647f0119afeef6f32/ros/atlas_msgs/msg/AtlasSimInterfaceCommand.msg?at=default#cl-10) mode and set all [`k_effort[0:28]`](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/367704bdd08af4f8471da3d647f0119afeef6f32/ros/atlas_msgs/msg/AtlasSimInterfaceCommand.msg?at=default#cl-38) to 0 simultaneously (for example, see [`SetBDIStand()`](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/367704bdd08af4f8471da3d647f0119afeef6f32/ros/atlas_msgs/VRCPlugin.cpp?at=default#cl-1356) for reference).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0